# Release Manager 2013 for TFS not processing Web.Config.Token

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

Using the Release Template that came with Release Management Client (Update 2), we are trying to do an automated deployment using TFS Build and Release Management Server 2013 Update 2.

Everything went fine until we decided to start using tokenized Web.Config (Web.config.token) to help us manage our deployments.

It seemed simple enough, create the variables in the Release Template Components, and put matching __ VARIABLES__ in duplicate Web.config.token.

Set the Build Template to Process Build Tokens and hit go.

The build doesn't seem to actually process the token file and we are left with the original Web.config. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

It says it's processing the tokens but it doesn't actually do any of that.
    Build Log:

```
Overall Build Process
Overall build process
Update build number
Run on agent (reserved build agent {Redacted} Build - Agent 2)
Initialize environment
Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control
Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build
Compile, Test and Publish
Run optional script before MSBuild
Run MSBuild
Built {Redacted}.sln for default targets.
Built ${Redacted}.csproj for default targets.
Built $/{Redacted}/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.
Built $/{Redacted}.Database.sqlproj for default targets.
MSBuild Log File
Run optional script after MSBuild
Process the release
Get the Build Directory
If ProcessReleaseTokens is set
Initialize tokens
Prepare folder to search
Find all .token files
Process each .token file
Rename files
Assign
Remove read-only flag from x.y
Copy x.y.token to x.y
If ReleaseBuild is set
Try to release the build
Get the build details
Initialize release build variables
Get the Release Management install directory
Verify the Release Management install directory
Get the Release Management install directory (x64)
Get the Team Project Collection instance
If ConfigurationsToRelease is not set
Copy binaries to drop
Process each ConfigurationsToRelease
Release the build
Run the Release Management build process for the current configuration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Build starting process...
Processing using the following parameters:
TeamFoundationServerUrl: {Redacted}
TeamProjectName: {Redacted}
TeamProjectWithCollection: {Redacted}
BuildDefinitionName: {Redacted}
BuildNumber: {Redacted}
TargetStage:
Creating the release and waiting for deployment result...
Release was created and deployment was successful.
If a Release Build error cccurs
Skipped due to successful completion
Run optional script before Test Runner
Run VS Test Runner
Run optional script after Test Runner
Get Impacted Tests
Publish Symbols
Perform Final Actions On Agent
Copy binaries to drop
Reset the Environment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the build template containing the token file swapping logic, use the one available at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/09/how-to-modify-the-build-process-template-to-use-the-option-trigger-release-from-build.aspx). This is the most up to date.

Comment: Thanks, I did a diff on the two and it looks like I am using that one.

Comment: The log looks fine. Have you validated that on a build, the web.config.token file is copied to your output folder.

Comment: Also, check for case sensivity matching between your web.config and web.config.token files. I am actually not sure if the logic expects that or not, but good to validate anyway.

Comment: When we put the same tokens in the Web.config, they get properly replaced with the configuration variables. Looking at the Build Agent output folders, under ./src/ I can see the Web.config and Web.config.token and the Web.config has been replaced with the tokenized version. But under ./bin/_PublisedWebsites/ the Web.config is the original.

Comment: In further tests, the tokenized web.config (pre-variable replacement) is making it to ./bin/web.config   Just not into ./bin/_PublishedWebsites

Comment: Your comment about making sure the web.config and web.config.token were copied to the output folder got me on the right track. Now I have to use a couple extra steps in my release template, but I can now delete/rename the files into the correct positions. Thanks! Found this too late to be of use: http://lifeaccordingtoabel.blogspot.com/2014/05/tfs-2013-release-management-not.html

Comment: @joerage FWIW, I've encountered the same thing. It's a bug in the process template, I think.

Comment: @DanielMann You may be right. The file swapping logic may be running only after the publish is done (and therefore too late). We will have a look.